# jquery - change content of html <b> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have set of frames and html pages . I have selected one of the frames html element from another html page and I want to change the content using jquery.

Here , I want to change "test.com" to "something.com" . Please let me know , how to achieve this.

**HTML element in frame 0 :**

```
<span class="topmid-left">Connected to <b>My Site 'test.com' </b> </span>
```

**The same element can be selectable by jquery by setting context :**

```
**query -**  $("b",window.frames[0].document)

**result -** <b>​My Site 'test.com' ​</b>​
```

How to change the content of  tag here.

Thanks.

Comment: `$("b").text(YOUR_TEXT)` ? or  `$("span.topmid-left b").text(YOUR_TEXT)`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function(…)

Comment: Have you included `jQuery` ?

Comment: Yes . Thats why I am able to select the text.

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/L1rq4o7a/

Use jquery and add the following to your javascript:

```
$(".topmid-left b").html("My Site 'something.com'");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<script>
var str = 'your text';
$( "b" ).html( str );
or 
$("b").text(YOUR_TEXT)
</script>
```

[Learn More](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).text is not a function(…) –

Comment: try html , or check my link.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

**Html :**

```
<span class="topmid-left">Connected to <b>My Site 'test.com'</b> </span>
```

**Script :**

```
// return the inner text of <b>.
var boldText = $("span.topmid-left b").text(); 

// returns the array of length 3.
var splitArr = boldText.split('\''); 

// returns test.com
var text = splitArr[1];

// replace the text.com with abc(or any text you want).
var repText = boldText.replace(text, "xyz"); 

// [Output] My Site 'xyz'
console.log(repText);

// assign new text into html <b> tag.
$("span.topmid-left b").text(repText);
```

**Working Jsfiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/LxcLb012/2/